# JSON Decoder Swift 4.0

Tags: json, swift, swift4, decoder

I have a JSON response from an API call.

I'm trying to use the Swift JSON Decoder however, I am getting the following error. [As per attached image]  I'm assuming the JSON Decoder only works when you pull the JSON direct from a URL? - Correct me if I'm wrong. Is there a way to use the Swift JSONDecoder() on this API request with this result?  Image attached with some JSON in my console.

[image: Error, Request & JSON Result]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error says the decode method wants a `Data`, but you’re passing it a tuple containing an `[Product]` and a `ProductListMeta?`. In other words, you don’t have a JSON response. The JSON has already been decoded for you. Just use `productList.products`.

Comment: using productList.products is returning the same "Cannot convert value of type '[Product]' to expected argument type 'Data"

Comment: Use `productList.products` **instead of** trying to decode anything. All the decoding was already done for you because you are using the Moltin Swift library. You are not talking JSON directly.

Comment: I see.  Sorry this might sound very amateur but how do I then assign productList.products to my data model?

Comment: Whatever you were planning to do with the array returned by `decode(_:from:)`, you should do with `productList.products` instead.